# Issue while reading tab delimited text file?

Tags: java

I have a tab delimited file and i have to read the data from the file.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
data1   data2   data3
data1   data2   data3
```

if values are present for all columns then no isssues. the problem is sometimes the few columns may not contain values as below.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
data1           data3
data1   data2
```

in above data, am able to read first rows data as col2's value will be empty string.
But the second row's col3 has no data. here i get array index out of bounds exception.
why am i not getting empty string for the second row's col3?

i am using the code as below:

```
String dataFileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\some.txt";

         /**
          * Creating a buffered reader to read the file
          */
         BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                 new FileReader(dataFileName));

         String line;

         /**
          * Looping the read block until all lines in the file are read.
          */
         while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

             /**
              * Splitting the content of tabbed separated line
              */
             String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
             String value1 = datavalue[0];
             String value2 = datavalue[1];
             String value3 = datavalue[2];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but some common guidance. Instead of reinventing the wheel you should consider using some library to read inn CSV files. Like CSVReader: http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html

Comment: @philnate is correct, I was just writing the same comment. Most CSV libraries support arbitrary delimiters (e.g. tabs). I would recommend you switch sooner rather than later! It may help you solve this and other problems, such as quoted text etc.

Comment: why are you not using a database for this tabular structure

Comment: @Philnate I think this IS an answer to the question. Parsing CSV is one of those tasks that you do not want to reinvent. Parsing anything really.

Answer (score 3):

The lazy way would be something like:

```
...
String datavalue[] = Arrays.copyOf(line.split("\t"),3);
String value1 = datavalue[0];
String value2 = datavalue[1];
String value3 = datavalue[2];
...
```

Basically you are splitting the content and copying it to a new array in which the padded elements are null as documented:

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length.  For all indices that
>   are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
>   contain identical values.  For any indices that are valid in the copy
>   but not the original, the copy will contain null. Such
>   indices will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than
>   that of the original array. The resulting array is of exactly the same
>   class as the original array.

Answer (score 2):

[String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) by default merges duplicate separators into one. You should use a negative second parameter:

```
String datavalue[] = (line+"\t\t\t").split("\t",-1);
```

Also - in case the original file is missing trailing tabs you can add extra tabs to the line to stop this breaking your code.